# Undefined control sequence in algorithmic package

Tags: algorithmic

[image: The code]

I started to write this algorithm in LaTeX but I got these errors and I don't know what should I do. I used the `algorithmic` and the `algorithm` packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code example comes from the [`algorithmicx` package](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). So, you'd need to use

```
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
```

in your preamble (and remove any reference to `algorithmic`, which is from the [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)). Also don't include [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) as it is not compatible with your implementation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid's algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The gcd of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is 0}
        \State $a \gets b$
        \State $b \gets r$
        \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \EndWhile
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```